# AWK Script to read some parameters from log file and Insert that data to Oracle DB table

Tags: shell-script, awk, sql

I have a requirement to read some parameters from log file and then use this data in an Insert statement to create records in a a database table.

Input is log file testapi.log which may consists of below lines or more-

```
[2018-05-20T12:59:06,911] [RQST: rqst_4C82-BAF7-F8A7-D31E | HC: 2853] - [pool-8-thread-7] - DEBUG - com.test.webapp.services.external.BaseExecuteExternalCall - Line 207 - Cut off date in Update statement 2018-05-25
[2018-05-20T12:59:06,915] [RQST: rqst_4C82-BAF7-F8A7-D31E | HC: 2853] - [pool-8-thread-7] - DEBUG - com.test.webapp.services.external.BaseExecuteExternalCall - Line 323 - Settlement serv ID column position37 null 
[2018-05-20T12:59:06,915] [RQST: rqst_4C82-BAF7-F8A7-D31E | HC: 2853] - [pool-8-thread-7] - DEBUG - com.test.webapp.services.external.BaseExecuteExternalCall - Line 328 - TEST_ID column position 39 588712469 
[2018-05-20T12:59:06,915] [RQST: rqst_4C82-BAF7-F8A7-D31E | HC: 2853] - [pool-8-thread-7] - DEBUG - com.test.webapp.services.external.BaseExecuteExternalCall - Line 330 - UPDATE_CRTE_DT column position 40 1 
[2018-05-20T12:59:06,918] [RQST: rqst_4C82-BAF7-F8A7-D31E | HC: 2853] - [588712469] - INFO - com.test.webapp.services.external.TransactionProcessing - Line 121 - Service thread was notified ExecuteExternalCall processing completed; proceeding, timeOutStatus=GATEWAY_RESPONSE_RECEIVED
[2018-05-20T12:59:06,919] [RQST: rqst_4C82-BAF7-F8A7-D31E | HC: 2853] - [588712469] - INFO - com.test.webapp.services.functions.PaymentTransactionService - Line 823 - requestType="PAYMENT",partnerName="RegPartner4MPQRIND",partnerId="2853",lob="PERSON_TO_MERCHANT",tranType="PAY",paymentType="P2M",amount="1.20",currency="356",processor="ABD",network="TestNetwork",cardNetworkBinRangeId="938889",responseCode="00",transactionLocalDateTime="2017-09-22T13:22:11-05:30",systemTraceAuditNumber="351893",cardAcceptorTerminalId="ABCD1234",gatewayTime="15",cardBrand="MASTERCARD",cardbin="529992",acctNumLastFour="0277",issuer="MTF INTERNAL MEMBER ID - INDIA",binCountry="IND",binCurr="INR",fundAvailability="IMMEDIATE",status="APPROVED",reqRefId="rqst_4C82-BAF7-F8A7-D31E",custRefNum="TRNREF_20180524125902781",senderCountry="IND",senderState="MO",senderCity="OFallon",recipientCountry="IND",recipientState="TX",recipientCity="Dallas",mccUsedForTransaction="6536",statementDescriptor="testmerchant",reconDataCustomFieldName="Paymentid:123|tranid:456|reference:789"
[2018-05-20T12:59:06,919] [RQST: rqst_4C82-BAF7-F8A7-D31E | HC: 2853] - [588712469] - INFO - com.test.webapp.services.APIsServices - Line 1059 - Transaction Execution Response: {"sc":200,"transaction":{"transactionID":588712469},"transaction":{"transactionID":588712469,"cardNetworkBinRangeId":938889,"networkMerchantCategoryCode":"6536","status":"AVAILABLE","statusSource":"PROCESSED","statusDestination":"PROCESSED","networkSendTime":"24 05 2018, 12:59:06.895 PM","networkReceiveTime":"24 05 2018, 12:59:06.910 PM","network":"MoneySend","retrievalReferenceNumber":"814412351893","systemTraceAuditNumber":"351893","moneysendUniqueTransactionReference":"0000000000588712467","createdTime":"24 05 2018, 05:59:06.910 PM","processedTime":"24 05 2018, 05:59:06.910 PM","networkReferenceNum":"392694744","authorizationId":"0087C5","walletIdentifier":"","paymentAccountReference":"","mappedCardId":"","mappedCardExpiry":"","tokenRequestorId":"","paymentUid":"","fpid":"","rc":"00","responseCodeCategory":"APPROVED","responseDesc":"Approved","processor":"B","fundsAvailability":"Immediate"},"ep":0} , request TRNREF_20180524125902781
[2018-05-20T12:59:06,924] [RQST: rqst_4C82-BAF7-F8A7-D31E | HC: 2853] - [588712469] - INFO - com.test.webapp.services.APIsServices - Line 1084 - Completed request for method omney-depositFunds-oneTimeTrans ReferenceId: TRNREF_20180524125902781
[2018-05-20T12:59:14,522] [RQST:  | HC: ] - [Thread-85] - DEBUG - com.test.webapp.listener.reversal.AutoReversalManager - Line 109 - updated testparm size = 12
[2018-05-20T12:59:15,167] [RQST:  | HC: ] - [588712465] - DEBUG - com.test.webapp.services.APIsServices - Line 195 - 2:/checkstatus
[2018-05-20T12:59:15,169] [RQST:  | HC: ] - [588712465] - INFO - com.test.webapp.services.APIsServices - Line 1059 - Transaction Execution Response: {"sc":200,"checkStatus":{"status":200,"hostName":"cjb4stl20","containerName":"Accel","availSw":"Y"},"ep":0} , request 
[2018-05-20T12:59:15,169] [RQST:  | HC: ] - [588712465] - INFO - com.test.webapp.services.APIsServices - Line 1084 - Completed request for method null ReferenceId: 
[2018-05-20T12:59:16,798] [RQST:  | HC: ] - [Thread-86] - DEBUG - com.test.webapp.listener.clearing.epx.TestManager - Line 128 - updated testparm size = 12
[2018-05-20T12:59:16,799] [RQST:  | HC: ] - [Thread-86] - DEBUG - com.test.webapp.listener.clearing.epx.TestManager - Line 129 - Using batch for clearing = true
[2018-05-20T12:59:24,545] [RQST:  | HC: ] - [Thread-85] - DEBUG - com.test.webapp.listener.reversal.AutoReversalManager - Line 109 - updated testparm size = 12
[2018-05-20T12:59:34,216] [RQST:  | HC: ] - [588712465] - DEBUG - com.test.webapp.services.APIsServices - Line 195 - 2:/checkstatus
[2018-05-20T12:59:34,217] [RQST:  | HC: ] - [588712465] - INFO - com.test.webapp.services.APIsServices - Line 1059 - Transaction Execution Response: {"sc":200,"checkStatus":{"status":200,"hostName":"cjb4stl20","containerName":"Accel","availSw":"Y"},"ep":0} , request 
[2018-05-20T12:59:34,217] [RQST:  | HC: ] - [588712465] - INFO - com.test.webapp.services.APIsServices - Line 1084 - Completed request for method null ReferenceId: 
[2018-05-20T12:59:34,568] [RQST:  | HC: ] - [Thread-85] - DEBUG - com.test.webapp.listener.reversal.AutoReversalManager - Line 109 - updated testparm size = 12
[2018-05-20T12:59:44,591] [RQST:  | HC: ] - [Thread-85] - DEBUG - com.test.webapp.listener.reversal.AutoReversalManager - Line 109 - updated testparm size = 12
[2018-05-20T12:59:46,800] [RQST:  | HC: ] - [Thread-86] - DEBUG - com.test.webapp.listener.clearing.epx.TestManager - Line 128 - updated testparm size = 12
[2018-05-20T12:59:46,800] [RQST:  | HC: ] - [Thread-86] - DEBUG - com.test.webapp.listener.clearing.epx.TestManager - Line 129 - Using batch for clearing = true
[2018-05-20T12:59:50,030] [RQST:  | HC: ] - [588712465] - DEBUG - com.test.webapp.services.APIsServices - Line 195 - 2:/checkstatus
[2018-05-20T12:59:50,031] [RQST:  | HC: ] - [588712465] - INFO - com.test.webapp.services.APIsServices - Line 1059 - Transaction Execution Resp
```

I need to apply some filters - paymentType as P2M and processor as ABD  and retrieve the following values - amount, responseCode, acctNumLastFour etc.

Then, I need to use these values in Insert statement to create records in a database table in Oracle.

edit

I have tried below code -

```
awk -F' - ' '{
    n = split($NF,a,",");
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++) {
            split(a[i],b,"=");
            kv[b[1]]=b[2]
    }
}

kv["processor"]=="\"ABD\"" && kv["paymentType"]=="\"P2M\""
{ 
print "responseCode:\t" kv["responseCode"], "tranType:\t" kv["tranType"],  "amount:\t", kv["amount"], "accountNumberLastFour:\t" kv["acctNumLastFour"]}' testapi.log
```

which is printing same records several times and also can't retrieve those values in to shell or in insert SQL queries

**expected result** (values should be available in bash variables so they can be used to insert in to SQL)-

responseCode="00", tranType="PAY", amount = "1.20", processor = "ABD", accountNumberLastFour="0277"

Comment: post the expected result for your current input content

Comment: actual is `acctNumLastFour="0277"` but not `accountNumberLastFour="1234"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk -F',' \
'/paymentType="P2M"/ && /processor="ABD"/{
     $1=$2=$3=$4=$5;
     for (i=6; i<=NF; i++) 
         if ($i ~ /(paymentType|processor|amount|responseCode|acctNumLastFour|tranType)=/){
             split($i, item, "="); 
             arr[item[1]] = item[2]
         }
          print arr["processor"], arr["paymentType"], arr["responseCode"], \
                arr["tranType"], arr["amount"], arr["acctNumLastFour"]
}' testapi.log \
| while read -r processor paymentType responseCode tranType amount acctNumLastFour; do
    # processing all obtained variables
    echo "$paymentType";
    # ... preparing SQL statement
done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will verify this against my script and update. If i add more parameters to be retrieved, does this line $1=$2=... has to be changed as well?

Comment: as for adding more parameters: it would depend if those occur before `tranType="PAY"` parameter or after it.

Comment: This is what I am using now and values print differently with the above code as there are more params - 

`awk -F',' \
'/paymentType="P2M"/ && /processor="BNC"/{
     $1=$2=$3=$4=$5=$6=$7=$8=$9=$10;
     for (i=10; i<=NF; i++) 
         if ($i ~ /(responseCode|tranType|systemTraceAuditNumber|custRefNum|amount|acctNumLastFour|cardAcceptorTerminalId|transactionLocalDateTime)=/){`

Comment: what you are using is wrong `$1=$2=$3=$4=$5=$6=$7=$8=$9=$10`. The above solution works fine for your current input fragment

Comment: Its printing like this after changing back to your code  - frist record seems to be printing incorrect values 
`responseCode: "00"
tranType: "FUND"
systemTraceAuditNumber: "TRNREF_20180524125323809"
custRefNum: "1.20"
amount: "0149"
acctNumLastFour:
cardAcceptorTerminalId:
transactionLocalDateTime: 
                                                responseCode: "00"
tranType: "PAY"
systemTraceAuditNumber: "351883"
custRefNum: "TRNREF_20180524125323809"
amount: "1.20"
acctNumLastFour: "0277"
cardAcceptorTerminalId: "ABCD1234"
transactionLocalDateTime: "2017-09-22T13:22:11-05:30"`

Comment: If empty values are there then it seems it is assigning to incorrect values.. @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: what can I say: you are getting it wrong OR you have posted non-actual input content